# How to loop multiple jQuery Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to loop these functions together so they replay when the last one finishes but I can't manage to figure out how.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#main').animate({
      height: 70,
      width: 300
    }, 200);
  }, 500);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#main').animate({
      height: 350,
      width: 350
    }, 200)
    $(".title").css("display", "none")
    $(".1").css("display", "block");
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#main').animate({
      height: 150,
      width: 350
    }, 200)
    $(".title").css("display", "none")
    $(".1").css("display", "none")
    $(".2").css("display", "block");
  }, 1500);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#main').animate({
      height: 70,
      width: 300
    }, 200)
    $(".title").css("display", "none")
    $(".1").css("display", "none")
    $(".2").css("display", "none")
    $(".3").css("display", "block");
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
#main {
  width: 0px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 70px;
  top: 50px;
}

.styled {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: arial;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}

.social {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" class="banner">
  <div class="styled title">name.</div>
  <div class="styled social 1">/1</div>
  <div class="styled social 2">/2</div>
  <div class="styled social 3">/3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/queue/

Comment: You know .animate has a callback that you can use, right? You can also delve into using promises with jquery animations which would allow you to setup a .then chain. You can't really rely on setTimeouts all set at the same time actually finishing in the exact durations that you set them to.

Comment: Thanks @Steve, I bookmarked that and will look more into it.

Comment: @KevinB I was aware of the callback function but I wasn't executing it properly, my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick all of you code in a function, and make the callback of the final one a function call of the root function.

```
function myFunction(){
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#main').animate({
      height: 70,
      width: 300
    }, 200);
  }, 500);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#main').animate({
      height: 350,
      width: 350
    }, 200)
    $(".title").css("display", "none")
    $(".1").css("display", "block");
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#main').animate({
      height: 150,
      width: 350
    }, 200)
    $(".title").css("display", "none")
    $(".1").css("display", "none")
    $(".2").css("display", "block");
  }, 1500);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#main').animate({
      height: 70,
      width: 300
    }, 200)
    $(".title").css("display", "none")
    $(".1").css("display", "none")
    $(".2").css("display", "none")
    $(".3").css("display", "block");

    myFunction();
  }, 2000);
}
```

Lastly, you need this to call it the first time.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    myFunction();
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben, I really appreciate it. I knew about the callback but had no idea how to implement it correctly. But your answer is greatly appreciated, thank you.